# Create an invoice for stripe payments

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

I'm using Stripe for one-time payments and subscriptions.
To create a payment, I use Stripe Checkout:

```
\Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'customer' => 'cus_XXXXX',
    'success_url' => '',
    'cancel_url' => '',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode' => ($isSubscription ? 'subscription' : 'payment'),
    'line_items' => [...]
]);

header('Location: '.$checkout_session->url);
exit;
```

This code automatically create an invoice for subscription mode but not for one-time payments.
I've tried this to create a new invoice but how can I do to make it related to previous payment, closed and paid?

```
$stripe = new Stripe\StripeClient('xxx');
$stripe->invoiceItems->create([
    'customer' => 'cus_XXXXX',
    'amount' => '1000',
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum...'
]);
$invoice = $stripe->invoices->create([
    'customer' => 'cus_XXXXX',
]);
```

Comment: In normal subscription creation, you can make use of the `add_invoice_items` https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=curl#create_subscription-add_invoice_items; however, I don't Stripe supports that on Checkout yet.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to create an invoice for each payment mark paid.
This, however, doesn't link them to a payment.

On the webhook `checkout.session.completed` do the following:

```
$stripe = new Stripe\StripeClient('xxx');

// Create invoice lines
$stripe->invoiceItems->create([
    'customer' => 'cus_XXXXX',
    'amount' => '1000',
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum...'
]);

// Create invoice
$invoice = $stripe->invoices->create([
    'customer' => 'cus_XXXXX',
]);

// Finalize and mark invoice paid outside of Stripe
$invoice->finalizeInvoice();
$invoice->pay(['paid_out_of_band' => true]);
```

Comment: Were you able to link the invoice to the payment by doing so?

Comment: @EDo no sorry, I couldn't find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/post-payment-invoices

> To enable invoice creation, set invoice_creation[enabled] to true when
> creating a Checkout session.