# How do you generate a stripe invoice after a successfull checkout session

Tags: stripe-payments, invoice

Quite suprisingly, it is not possible to automatically generate an invoice after as [successfull checkout session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030044/how-do-you-generate-a-paid-invoice-pdf-for-a-stripe-checkout-session) with Stripe.
An invoice must always come before a payment in the stripe system.

I am left with having to recreate the invoice through a bunch of API calls fetching the [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) or the [CheckoutSession](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) that was just performed to recompute the data for the invoice and mark it as paid (not even sure I can retrieve everything I need)

This seems quite hacky... Is this the right way to do it or shall I just handle invoicing outside of stripe  (quite annoying too) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057233/create-an-invoice-for-stripe-payments this gives an answer but I'm not sure if the invoice connects to the payment

Answer (score 4):

just want clarify if you need Invoice or Receipt, because they are two different things

- Invoice is something you send to customer to ask for payment (before payment)
- Receipt is a proof of succeeded payment (after payment)

My understanding is that the payment is already collected upon a succeeded checkout session, so you probably want to send receipts to customers. To enable email receipts, you can go to [Settings -> Emails](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails) and tick the `Email customers about Successful payment` box. Please note that emails won't be sent in test mode.

Comment: I indeed want an invoice and not a receipt ! Customers are asking for invoices (a lot of infos are missing from the receipt) for legal reasons

Comment: Exactly, I'm also looking for a solution

Comment: OpenAI has a link to invoice after successful Checkout on their subscription page, so it seems, that it IS possible

Comment: You can now send a paid invoice through Checkout. See this for details: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts?payment-ui=checkout

Comment: is there a way to generate an invoice after the payment with Stripe?

Comment: Yes you can now ask Stripe to generate a paid invoice. Check this link for details: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts?payment-ui=checkout#paid-invoices

Answer (score -4):

Let me explain a solution that you can use to generate invoices after payment in stripe. This solution is based on Zapier connectors.
There are three systems that we should connect.

- Stripe
- Zapier
- Plumsail Documents

First, you have to set up a Stripe connection to Zapier. Go to Zapier, create a Zap, find the Stripe connection, and select "New Payment" as the trigger event. Then, connect your Stripe account with Zapier and make a test in Zap.  If everything ok, go to the second step.

Second. After you have done the Zap connection for Stripe, go to Plumsail Documents, create the process, and make a template for your invoice.

Third. Set up a Plumsail Documents connection to Zapier. Go to your Zap (where you have made the connection to Stripe before), find the Plumsail Documents action, and set the Start Process as Action Event. Next, you have to select your process and match output data from Stripe payment with your invoice template in Plumsail Documents.

It seems a bit complicated, so you can [read the article](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/user-guide/processes/examples/generate-invoices-after-payment-in-stripe.html) with a more detailed description of this solution. Also, there are screenshots for all processes.

As a result, you will get a fully automated custom invoice generation whenever you will get a payment in Stripe.

Max, product manager at Plumsail.